# Can I add a shortcut in xubuntu to make a top panel (one with window buttons) appear on the screen even if in fulscreen mode?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xubuntu, xfce

When I used windows xp, when I pressed a key with the windows logo, start menu opened and the bottom panel with window buttons appeared no matter what. Even in a fullscreen mode it was possible to click windows button, then Start menu opened and window buttons panel appeared. On xubuntu when I press a hotkey to open applications menu, it opens, but the pannel don't appear.

Is it possible to make panel appear on hotkey? Maybe together with applications menu when I press a hotkey to open applications menu.

Comment: [Can I unhide the panel in XFCE 4.10 using a key press rather than using mouse cursor hover to reveal it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244466)

Comment: How did you make the "windows" key open the Application Menu? That's what I'm trying to figure that out ....

Comment: settings -> keyboard -> application shortcuts: `xfdesktop --menu` `<Primary>Escape`

Comment: That opens a menu, but not the "Application Menu" that's normally in the top left corner. Do you happen to know how to open that one?

Comment: This opens "application menu" on the top left corner(i have it on bottom left corner) on my system.

Comment: Interesting. For me it opens the same menu as a right click would, wherever the mouse pointer happens to be.