# Can I unhide the panel in Xfce using a key press rather than using mouse cursor hover to reveal it?

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

I would like to be able to unhide the Xfce panel by pressing a key instead of placing the mouse cursor at the edge of the screen.

I'm running Xubuntu 12.04 but updated to Xfce 4.10

Comment: hmmm.. I think I could come up with something that would _move_ your mouse over there on a key press.  Would that do what you want?

Comment: @iSeth - if nothing better is possible then yes. But optimally I'd like to able to press a key and see the panel regardless of where the cursor is...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take the following commands and bind them to separate Super-key combinations:

**Commands for Xfce 4.12 through Xfce 4.14:**

The following commands are now used to set the auto-hide properties:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide-behavior -s 0
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide-behavior -s 1 
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide-behavior -s 2
```

**Commands for Xfce 4.10:**

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide -s false
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide -s true
```

**Update: 12/09/2018**: As mentioned in the comments, the above commands are no longer supported.

*Command Values:*

The value '0' is used for *'never'* auto-hide. Value '1' is for *'intelligently'* auto-hiding the panel, and '2' is used to set the value to *'always'* auto-hide.

**Setting the key-bindings:**

This can be done by either selecting, Applications Menu → Settings → Keyboard → Application Shortcuts, or by running `xfce4-keyboard-settings` from the command line(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).

I've bound the first command to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (to 'unhide' the panel). For the second command, I am binding <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> (to 'hide' the panel).

As you can see in the commands above, the behavior is only changed on a single panel(In this case, panel-0 is being modified).

You may notice a slight delay while the panel changes state.

More details on the `xfconf-query` command can be found in the [Xfce documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query) or from [this thread in the Xfce forum](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6220).

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that and got `xconf command not found` error.  What version of Xfce do you use?

Comment: @iSeth The command is `xfconf`, not `xconf`. ;-) The command has been available since xfce 4.6. I'm running xfce 4.10 from this PPA http://ppa.launchpad.net/xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10/ubuntu

Comment: Ah, your right.  Works now.  +1

Comment: You can also use the `toggle` option in Xfce 4.10 and just bind a single command to one key: i.e. `xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide -T`

Comment: @Mik Nice find! I was unaware of that option flag.

Comment: Just to update on the later version of xfce4-panel. The latest xfce4-panel do not have the 'autohide' property. Instead there is 'autohide-behavior' and no longer a boolean, but a numeric value of 0, 1, or 2. 0: never hide, 1: intelligent hide, 2: always hide. To achieve the same outcome, you can use `xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide-behavior -s 0` and `xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide-behavior -s 2`.

Comment: This offers a solution to switch between "display" and "autohide".  Ideally, there should be a solution to switch between "display" and "hide".

Answer (score 4):

## Try this workaround:

Install `xte` and `xdotool` with `sudo apt-get install xdotool xautomation`

You can use `xdotool` to find the x,y coordinates of the mouse.  Open a terminal type `xdotool getmouselocation` then move the mouse somewhere where it will activate the panel and hit enter.  You will get some output like:

```
findclient: 62914741
findclient: 6291474  
x:1282 y:1079 screen:0 window:62914741
```

What's important here is: `x:1282 y:1079`, which gives us the x,y coordinates of the mouse.

Now type `xte 'mousemove 1282 1079'` (replacing `1282 1079` with the coordinates you got earlier).  That should move the mouse where you want.

You can use `xbindkeys` to bind this command to a key on the keyboard.  I can add instructions upon request or you can set it in Xubuntu's keyboard settings.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

@JQuigley pointed out "This no longer works..." see comments.

---

As Kevin said, you can use xfconf, but I'd do it this way:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide -T
```

The `-T` toggles the true/false value.
This way, you can use the same key to hide/unhide.

To get more options do:

```
xfconf-query --help
```

I wanted to make a comment to the answer from Kevin, since it's what got me on the right track. But I'm new here, not enough reputation..

Comment: This no longer works unfortunately; the autohide property seems to have been replaced with autohide-behavior, which is an integer that can be 0, 1, or 2.  But the two-key approach still works.  Also I imagine a person could write a little toggle script of some sort to maybe store the state in a file or something and allow a one-key strategy to work again.

Comment: @JQuigley oh, thanks for pointing it out. I'm not on xfce anymore... If that's the case I'd go with a script to read the current value and change it accordingly (external file is prone to errors).

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a couple of years late to the party, but just for anyone who might see this in the future: Here is a bash script that toggles autohide in the new system, simply save this in a text file somewhere, run `chmod +x file/that/i/saved` and set the script to a key in Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cur=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide-behavior)
if [[ cur -eq 0 ]]; then
  nxt=1
else
  nxt=0
fi
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/autohide-behavior -s $nxt
```

Answer (score 2):

topisani's script above still works well in xfce 4.12. 
You can change the target panel by changing `panel-0` in the script to `panel-1` or `panel-2` etc. Don't forget that there are two lines to change.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

It's been pointed out in a comment that the autohide property has been changed to something else, and -T doesn't work with the new one :/

---

So, while I was fooling around with  this, I made a little ruby script to toggle all panels at the same time. It seems to work.

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

#Toggle all panels' autohide property in xfce4
# fede s.
out = `xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -l`.split
out.inject(Array.new) {|res, val|
    m= /panel-([0-9]+)/.match(val);                 #get the panel numbers
    if m then res.push(m[1]) end;                   #add only if it matches
    res}.sort.uniq.each do                          #filter duplicates
        | num |
            `xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-#{num}/autohide -T` #here is the command that will repeat for every panel found
    end
```

It's probably not the best way to do it, and I don't really know much about ruby, so feel free to throw me in the fire! :P

If Someone want's to use it:

1. make sure you have ruby installed.
2. copy it to a file wherever you see fit (I have mine as `~/scripts/xfce/toogleautohide.rb`).
3. Make it executable

   ```
   chmod +x path/to/your/script
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both 1. moving cursor with `xdotool mousemove_relative` and 2. changing panel property hide=always/never with `xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel`. But the best behavior was with 3. changing x window state. Script example:

```
#!/bin/bash

#command will get several uids (if there are 2 panels then probably 2). Need to find out which one we need.
windowUids=$(wmctrl -Glx | awk '/[Xx]fce4\-[Pp]anel.*[Xx]fce4\-[Pp]anel/ {if ($3 !~ /-9999/) print $1}')

#i need the panel with y coordinate = 0, while other panel has other value
for uid in $windowUids
do 
  yCoord=$(xdotool getwindowgeometry $uid | grep Position | cut -d',' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1)
  if [ $yCoord -eq 0 ]
  then 
    WINDOW_UID=$uid
    break
  fi
done

#if window is viewable then hide, otherwise show
if xwininfo -all -id $WINDOW_UID | grep IsViewable
then
  xdotool windowminimize --sync $WINDOW_UID
else
  xdotool windowmap --sync $WINDOW_UID
fi
```

Here i find out which panel to process by y coordinate, you may need your own check e.g. by x coordinate or by width/heigth (see what `xdotool` can get).
Also do not forget to set "Dont reserve space on borders"=true in panel properties, or other windows will be changing their own sizes.